# Jquery get element class with rails throws error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox

I use the following JQuery script to update a specific element when the user clicks on a button:

```
$(function(){
 $("#item_<%= @detail.itemID %>").addClass('selected').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'pages/item', :item => @detail.item, :@order => @detail.order) %>");
)};
```

Here is the relevant element in my view:

```
<tr class = "item_row">
<% items.each do |item| %>
<td class = "item_data <%= item_select(item)%>", id = "item_<%= item.itemID %>" >
    <%= render 'pages/item', :item => item %>
</td>
<% end %>
```

I am working with Rails and JQuery. The script updates properly with Chrome, but with Firefox the following error gets thrown (I debugged with Firebug):

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #item_<%= @detail.itemID %>
```

I use this rails bit of code because I want update only the specific item that relates to what the user clicked. Clearly I need to adapt my JQuery so Firefox can handle the rails element of my code properly, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that that javascript code is inside an asset file.  You can do this but if you set the file to use erb by adding a .erb to the file name.  But in your case, you want to evaluate a ruby expression that uses an instance variable which can only be done when you have access to the variable.  If you move that javascript function inside the view, you should be able to run it without any errors.

Comment: Hi jvnill, what you said makes sense intuitively, but how come Chrome is able to run the script in the asset file?

Comment: the asset files are being served as is when no interpreter is needed before serving them. I'm guessing this specific javascript code is under a file called `some_js.js` which doesn't need any conversion so it is served as is. any error you have on this files will only appear on the browser.  try adding a `.erb` to this file then you'll get the error.

Comment: Hey thanks jvnill, actually the files do have the .erb extension to them! I'm still searching for the root cause of the problem.

Comment: really? then it's not being rendered properly. try clearing your cache and look at the asset file downloaded by the browser

Comment: Hi jvnill I found the error and  it has to do with Firefox throwing an error when I set up my table across a form and a button outside the form. I fixed it now - thanks for your help, I acknowledge the info wasn't in the question so you has no way of finding this out.